# segue destination controller not set after setting segue id

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, segue

I am new to Xamarin development and I am trying to build simple IOS app.

I have a situation with 2 `ViewController`s with specific classes ( `FirstViewController`, `SecondViewController`) and `segue` set between them.

When I try to pass data from the first one to the second in this code, everything is ok :

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

    var viewController = (SecondViewController)segue.DestinationViewController;
    viewController.Number = 1;
}
```

But when I set an identifier to `segue`, I get a `NullReferenceException`. There is no `SecondViewController` in `DestinationViewController`, but `UIViewController`.

What is even weirder is that when i remove the identifier, the exception is still there. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when you change the namespace of a ViewController it gets detached from the Storyboard View.